# Strange PHP session behavior - resets all values

Tags: php, session

I need to reset session each time the user goes back to index.php, in the index i got

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['prevail'])) session_unset();
?>
```

where `$_SESSION['prevail']` is first session variable that is set on the next page. At the moment when I visit any page it resets session just like it was loading index.php before loading the page (with isn't possible cause I use permanent links to pages and they aren't sharing any header.

It also happens when I put `session_destroy()` in other files.

On the server the app is in directory public_html/app and in public_html is wordpress installed. App has it's own subdomain though. Any suggestion will be appreciated :)

Comment: Does you browser block cookies? If so is there the session ID in the request string? Otherwise your script does not know which is the current session and creates a new one.

Comment: Cookies are working correctly, session ID seems to work correctly

Answer (score -2):

> I need to reset session each time the user goes back to index.php

i will use below code to do so:
index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION['prevail'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['prevail']); // only unset that session
}
```

Try this.. ;)

Comment: No need to use `isset()` and `!empty()` in the same if clause

Comment: I want to unset session, not the prevail variable, further more, it still is a problem cause it unsets even when I visit pages other than index.php (the unset clausule is only in index.php)